# Acquiring stream from pool

Tags: asp.net-mvc, memcached

I have a deployed ASP.NET MVC application and sometimes it is throwing the error listed below.

> Acquiring stream from pool. xx.x.xx.xxx:xxxxx 
>   [DEBUG] � Socket 04e15a2f-0331-4d7c-b0a8-c8a0e24dac30 was reset 
>   [DEBUG] � Socket was reset. 04e15a2f-0331-4d7c-b0a8-c8a0e24dac30 
>   [DEBUG] � Releasing socket 04e15a2f-0331-4d7c-b0a8-c8a0e24dac30 
>      [DEBUG] � Are we alive? True

I could not identify what is causing the error.

Comment: Are you using memcached?

Comment: yes it is there

Comment: Which client are you using?

Comment: enyim memcached